# Embedded DHT11, temperature turns to 0 after first print

Tags: c, embedded

So, I am trying to set up a DHT11 in a C environment to try to learn some more embedded software programming.

I've taken help from [other sources](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/42472392/#) and the [documentation](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf) to create this and the temperature shows only once and then defaults to 0.

I am using an Arduino as microcontroller (because it is the only one I have) and use a Linux Ubuntu environment to load up the program in to the microcontroller.

In the end, the code looks like this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#include "dht.h"

// Trying to set up the DHT11 so it can be used in this project
void read() {

  // The bits are for to get the temperature values in.
  // reqCounter is for the request later on.
  uint8_t bits[5];

  // Setting up the DDRD as OUTPUT and PORTD as HIGH
  DDRD |= (1 << DDD5);
  PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);
  _delay_ms(100);

  /*
   * Makes an request to get the data from the DHT11
   * Set the the PORTD5 as LOW
  */
  PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5);
  _delay_ms(18);
  // Setting it back to high and DDRD as an input
  PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);
  _delay_us(1);
  DDRD &= ~(1 << DDD5);

  /*
   * Checking to see if the ACK is happening
  */
  _delay_us(39);
  if ((PIND & (1 << PIND5))) {
    return;
  }
  _delay_us(80);
  if (!(PIND & (1 << PIND5))) {
    return;
  }
  _delay_us(80);

  // Holds the temperature 
  uint8_t temp;

  // Reading the data
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Create a for loop that looks in to every 8 bits
    for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      // While it isn`t high, loop this while loop
      while (!(PIND & (1 << PIND5)))
              ;
        _delay_us(30);
        // Looking if the input is still high after 30us
        if (PIND & (1 << PIND5)) {
          temp |= (1 << (7-i));
        }
        // Wait until the input is low.
        while (PIND & (1 << PIND5))
          ;
    }
      // Put the temperature in the bit array
      bits[i] = temp;
  }

  // Resets the pins
  DDRD |= (1 << DDD5);
  PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);
  _delay_ms(100);

  uint8_t temperature ;
  //checks the sum and gets the temperature 
  if (bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3] == bits[4]) {
    temperature = bits[2];
  }

  printf("temperature : %d\n", temperature );
  /*printf("%d", bits[0]);
  printf("%d", bits[1]);
  printf("%d", bits[2]);
  printf("%d", bits[3]);
  printf("%d\n", bits[4]);*/
}
```

What this produces is just 15 once and then noting more. I've tried to blow on it to rise the temperature, but nothing happened.

What might be the issue here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please double check the indentation after your first while loop, it is inconsistent and logically misleading.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this `temp |= (1 << (7-i));`, It feels like it wants a `j` instead of an `i`. It initially also uses a non-initialised `temp`. I think you want to init temp to 0 in the outer `for`, before the inner `for`.

Comment: Let me know whether my comments solve the problem (write a comment here which includes "@Yunnosch"). Then I will make them an answer with some explanation.

Comment: I know I am supposed to be patient when waiting for feedback. But asking a question and then going off to bed is a habit which usually has a certain effect on my mood....

Comment: My answer may not fix your problem, but as it is it is semantically incorrect in any case. I have no idea what the expression `bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3] == bits[4]` is intended to do or even if it will work, but I am struggling with the plausibility - weird code.  A link to the data sheet of the temperature sensor and information on how it is connected would be helpful, and would a link to the mysterious _" other sources and the documentation"_.   Plenty of people could help without being familiar with the DHT11 or the I/O and processing needed to read it.

Comment: The posted code seems to be missing the statement; `#include <stdint.h>`.    What is/are the contents of the home grown file: `dht.h`?

Comment: The posted code does not match the wave forms and timing as specified on the [data sheet for the DHT11](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf)

Comment: The data sheet says only one bit is transmitted  for each cycle and each cycle has a starting sequence of low(50usec) followed by high( ) where the length of the high is 26-28usec for 0 bit and 70usec for 1 bit, followed by a low(50usec)... for the next bit,  after the last data bit is transmitted, then the output is held low for 50usec.   The posted code is NOT implementing this protocol.   Also, if the 50usec low sequences are not being transmitted, then the DHT11 is not transmitting the data,

Comment: regarding: `temp |= (1 << (7-i));`  The actual data bit is the value on `PIND & (1 << PIND5)`, not the current value of 'i' (nor the current value of 'j')  and since the variable `temp` has not been initialized to 0x00, The code needs to use the actual value, not some (1 << 7-i)

Comment: Note: since the DHT11 can take upto 30 seconds to respond, the initial wait for the initial response cannot be limited to 39usec

Comment: You never initialize your variables, simple as that. Enable compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: Hello.

Sorry for the late reply.
Yunnosch thank you for pointing out that I placed the temp wrong.
@Clifford The [link](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/42472392/#) and [data sheet] (https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf)
user3629249 should I maybe initialize temp as 0x00 and then increase the timer on the 29usec? Also, wouldn't the while loop just keep it waiting for the response?

Comment: @Ravoos SO is not a discussion forum; it is more like a Q&A wiki. Add the requested information to the question, not in comments.

Comment: I took a look at the code you based this on, and your changes seem unnecessary.  Especially changing the comment _"check checksum"_ to _"checks the sum"_ which is an entirely different thing - the code makes much more sense with the original comment!  It is not at all clear why you changed the given (and presumably working) code rather then just using it as it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thank you all for your help, but I have managed to find out a way to make it work.
If you want to know how, I have put it in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QxhHsN85) as a way for you all to see.

But in short, I made a change so it looks a bit more like this in the for loops:

```
    // Reading the data and starts with bits 0 up to 4
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        uint8_t result = 0;
    // I read every bit in the system to be able to get it in to the bits.
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            while (!(PIND & (1 << PIND5)))
                ; //wait for an HIGH input
        // delay for 30us
            _delay_us(30);
      //if the input is HIGH then I will put the data in result
            if (PIND & (1 << PIND5))
                result |= (1 << (7 - i));
            while (PIND & (1 << PIND5))
                ; //wait until input get LOW
        }
    //Put the result in the bit
        bits[j] = result;
    }
```

Sorry for any inconvenience and thank you all.

Comment: _a bit more_ or _exactly_ like that?  What use is a _bit more_?  It would take me a lot of work to see how/where this differs from either your original code or the code you linked as a source in the original.  A good answer your highlight and explain those differences.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
  uint8_t temperature ;
  //checks the sum and gets the temperature 
  if (bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3] == bits[4]) {
    temperature = bits[2];
  }

  printf("temperature : %d\n", temperature );
```

If `bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3] == bits[4]` is `false`, then temperature is initialised (and may have any value - including zero or 15, one of those values is junk).

Perhaps:

```
static uint8_t temperature = 0 ;
```

So that when `bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3] != bits[4]`, the last valid temperature will be used.

Or more simply, if `temperature` is not to be used elsewhere :

```
  //checks the sum and gets the temperature 
  if (bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3] == bits[4]) 
  {
      printf( "temperature : %d\n", bits[2] ) ;
  }
```

What I imagine is happening here however is the uninitialised value of `temperature` happend to be 15 and you print it, then thereafter `bits[0] + bits[1] + bits[2] + bits[3] == bits[4]` becomes `true` and bits[2] is always zero.  In which case the error is in the input and values placed in `bits[]`, and this solution will result in the value *always* being zero.

Comment: Same kind of bug here also: `uint8_t temp;` ... `temp |= (1 << (7-i));`.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I don't doubt it, Yunnosch already mentioned it, but this was the obvious _always incorrect_ issue that did not require any knowledge or analysis of how the code is intended to work. In my experience, if an error that fundamental is made, there are likely to be others. From user3629249's comments that entire part is broken in any case.

Comment: Hey.

Thank you.

So, I changed it to ```static uint8_t temp = 0;``` and ```static uint8_t temperature = 0 ;``` and now I get 160 and then a trail of 184. It seems to be going in the right direction.
However, I still get the case that I can't change the temperature even when I blow on it.
Again, I am not the best at Embedded or software development (very much a junior) so I'd like to ask if there are any more problems you see.

Comment: On another note:
I tried to print all the bits by them selves to see how it looked. What I got was that all the bits first have a different value and then they all have 184.

Comment: @Ravoos temp needed initialised too, but it did not need to be static in fact that is an error.  Determining whether the algorithm is valid requires knowledge of the sensor as noted in my comments.  Other comments suggest that it is flawed.  You need to include the requested information in the question before I will consider it further.  That is if you respond to comments on improvements to the question by improving the question,  you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Hello, @Clifford
I've put in the information as you requested. I've managed to get it to show 52 now and then 125. Again, the problem with that the bits seem to then all instantly turn to 125.
Sorry for the late responses, I've had work and things outside of this.

Comment: @Ravoos No need to apologise, I will take another look at it later when I too get time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you have chosen to re-write (and break) the code at "[other sources](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/42472392/#)", and not simply used it as-is:

```
void read( void )
{
    printf("temperature : %d\n", (int)DHT11_GetData(DHT11_DATA_TEMPERATURE)) ;
}
```